# Distance between $u$ and $v$ is the same as distance between $v$ and $u$ in a transposed graph?

Tags: graphs

My question is what the title says. Given an weighted directed graph $G=(V,E)$ and the minimum distance between two vertexes $u$ and $v$, I want to know if the distance between $v$ and $u$ is always the same in $G^{T}$ (the graph with all edges inverted).

I did some tests and couldn't find a graph where this is false, but this proves nothing. What is the intuition behind proving this true (or false)?

**Edit:** Distance is just the sum of all weights in the path from $u$ to $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think about the path from $u \leadsto v$ in $G$.  Can you find a corresponding path $v \leadsto u$ in $G^T$?

Hint: Suppose there was a *shorter* path $v \leadsto u$ in $G^T$.  Can you think of any implications this would have for the distance from $u$ to $v$ in $G$?

Perhaps you can find some correspondence between paths in $G$ and paths in $G^T$ that will help you out.